# ¿Por qué "estar volado" se entiende como "estar loco"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

Leo en el DRAE la definición de "volado" y de "estar volado".

> **[volado](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=sTwizbODNDXX2g6BIUc6)**
>
> (Del part. de volar).
>
> (...)
>
> *estar alguien ~.*
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar inquieto, sobresaltado.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Perú. Estar distraído.

Sin embargo, en España se suele decir "estás volado" a alguien como sinónimo de "estás loco":

> - Ayer me comí veinte bocadillos de morcilla.
> - ¡Estás volado!

¿De dónde proviene esta acepción?

Veo que en Perú "volar" puede significar "estar drogado":

> **[volar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=sTwizbODNDXX2g6BIUc6)**
>
> (Del lat. volāre).
>
> 12. intr. Perú. Estar bajo los efectos de una droga alucinógena.

Pero solo en Perú. ¿Qué otra explicación puede tener el término? ¿O acaso yo lo uso mal?

Comment: Not only in peru, apparently in Chile also it means high on drugs. From El Cuaderno de Maya: "Se vistió con túnicas, sandalias y collares ordinarios de la India, pero estaba muy lejos de ser hippie: trabajaba, corría con una casa y una nieta, participaba en la comunidad y yo nunca la vi **volada** entonando cánticos en sánscrito."

Comment: No solo en Perú, acá en Colombia tambien significa lo mismo

Comment: En Chile estar volado se usa de forma coloquial para una persona que está drogada, frecuentemente después de fumar marihuana. Puede que estas dos formas coloquiales puestas aquí tengan relación con la expresion en Inglés " to be high "

Comment: Curioso, @fedorqui: yo siempre había pensado que era influencia del catalán "està volat", pero puede que esté totalmente equivocada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El significado de `¡Estás volado!`en España, es debido al significado de la DRAE, que dice: `"loc. verb. coloq. Estar inquieto, sobresaltado"`, especialmente por `sobresaltado`. Sobresaltado significa que haz superado los límites de algo "normal", como en tu ejemplo: `Ayer me comí veinte bocadillos de morcilla.`

Como mencioné antes, aquí la persona que comió los veinte bocadillos ha comido más de lo normal, entonces ahí es cuando se utiliza esta expresión.

Y el significado en Perú y también usado en México (yo soy de México), es debido a que cuando la gente se droga, imagina o alucina cosas por el efecto de las drogas, entonces en este caso es común decir la siguiente expresión:

> ¡Carlos esta echando a volar su imaginación!

Espero estos ejemplos te sean ayuda para aclarar tus dudas.

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** Simple, **volado**, hace referencia a "perder el juicio" como que la razón se le salio volando de su cabeza.

**2 -** Simplemente puede ser como la frase "estás en las nubes" no estás en la misma sintonia, no nos comprendes, estás en lo tuyo, por los aires, sin control, en las nubes o en la luna.

Answer (score 0):

Cuestión: ¿Por qué "estar volado" se entiende como "estar loco"?

---

Para entender la expresión y la conexión entre "estar volado" y "estar loco" hay que conocer y especificar que *volado/a* también se refiere a *ráfagas de viento*.

Las anteriores respuestas que he leído no inciden en la explicación y conexión de esta expresión, "*estar volado*" con "*estar loco*", la cual precisamente tiene su origen en el sur de España, exactamente en Tarifa, lugar considerado popularmente con más locos ó volaó's del territorio Hispano, aunque obviamente esto es relativo.

Sin embargo la fama ancestral "la locura como hija del viento", ha estado presente de forma permanente y siempre se ha considerado que la causa de estas perturbaciones era el viento, ya que Tarifa, situada en pleno estrecho de​ Gibraltar es conocida como la Capital Europea del viento, pues son más de trescientos los días al año que suele Eolo soplar con fuerza.

Cuando el viento sopla de levante durante muchos días, uno se siente abatido y deprimido, tendiendo a la tristeza y a la melancolía. Siempre encontrarás a los lugareños hablando de los muchos tarados que existen por la zona, ya que el viento afecta bastante, la gente se irrita y se pone de mal humor.

Es esta combinación de "volado/a" como ráfagas de viento y la cierta fama de locura que ancestralmente viene conectada con el lugar, la causa que ha dado lugar al dicho,   " ¡estar volao'! "  ó " ¡estas volao'! "como sinónimo de "*locura*" ó "*loco*", y que con el tiempo se ha ido extendido y hecho tan popular.

P.D. Aunque para los locales los verdaderos "locos" siguen siendo los deportistas del surf, el kitesurf y otros deportes, que se meten en el mar cuando ni los pescadores más avezados lo hacen.

Espero que haya ayudado a entenderlo. Saludos.

Diego M.